# VK Api execute. Загрузка фотографии с помощью метода execute

Tags: vkontakte-api

Как отправить картинку в личное сообщение, используя метод `execute`?

порядок действия понятен:

1. `photos.getMessagesUploadServer` - получить url для загрузки картинки
2. послать post запрос на этот url вместе с картинкой в формате `multipart/form data`.
3. `photos.saveMessagesPhoto` - загрузить изображение на сервер.
4. `messages.send` - отправить сообщение пользователю, (картинка в attachment)

но как послать post запрос в VKScript?

Сразу уточню, что необходимо 1 раз использовать `execute`, чтобы обойти лимит на 3 обращения к одному методу VK API в секунду. 
 Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

С execute такое сделать нельзя. Вы не нарушите правило трех обращений в секунду, поскольку загрузка картинки на указанный адрес не является обращением к API.

Comment: А также, сделать POST-запрос через метод execute тоже не получится.